# Heroku dynos: can I technically use less dynos in my Django setup?

Tags: django, heroku, django-channels

I'm using the following with my Django application:

1. [Django channels](https://channels.readthedocs.io/en/latest/)
2. [Celery with both regular and periodic tasks](http://www.celeryproject.org/)
3. Deployed on Heroku

My Procfile looks like this:

```
web: daphne artist_notify.asgi:channel_layer --port $PORT --bind 0.0.0.0 -v2
worker: python manage.py migrate --noinput && python manage.py runworker -v2
celerybeat: celery -A artist_notify beat -l info
celeryworker: celery -A artist_notify worker -l info
```

This combination seems to be expensive, and I'm wondering if I can make it better. I tried combining `celerybeat` and `celeryworker` (with `&&`) into one dyno called `celery`, like so:

```
celery: celery -A artist_notify beat -l info && celery -A artist_notify worker -l info
```

But that doesn't work, although other `&&` combinations do work. I'm wondering if I can maybe combine the workers from `worker` and `celeryworker`?

Comment: You can use the `-b` argument to start the normal worker with a beat.

Comment: @DanielRoseman Thanks for your help. [celery recommends not doing that](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/userguide/periodic-tasks.html#starting-the-scheduler): "You can also embed beat inside the worker by enabling the workers -B option, this is convenient if you’ll never run more than one worker node, but it’s not commonly used and for that reason isn’t recommended for production use". (I wonder *why* they recommend against it though...)